# Rails 3 & cancan: User should not be allowed to edit record but is able to? 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am trying to implement specific object (row) authorisation using cancan, I want it to work in a way that a user can only make a change(update/edit) to a `Record` if he/she has the role for that specific `Record`. after consulting the cancan docs I tried doing the following:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
     can :manage, Record do |record|
        user.can_edit(record)
     end
  end
end


class User
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles_as_editor, :through => :assignments, :class_name => "Role", :source => :role, :conditions => {:edit => true}
  def rec_as_editor
    self.roles_as_editor.collect{ |x| Record.where(:cp_secondary_id => x.record_id) }.flatten.uniq
  end

  def can_edit(rec)
    rec_as_editor.include?(rec)
  end
end
```

The `can_edit` method takes in a `Record` object and ensures that a User has the role necessary to make a change to it by returning true or false. this method is tested and works correctly so the problem seems to be with the CanCan code because when i try editing a Record that the user dosent hold the role for it still allows me to make changes to the Record, anyone know why this wont work?

If you require any further information please let me know through a comment.

Thank You

Comment: I remember reading in the CanCan docs something about putting a "cannot" for these type of things, and that the "cannot" should be declared after all the "cans". See the docs or try that out.

Comment: sorry i dont know what you mean, the ``can_edit`` method is a method i wrote in the ``user`` class. did i do something wrong?

Comment: How do the Role - Record associations look? a role belongs to one record but a key called cp_secondary_id has to match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you authorizing the resource in the controller?

you should have `load_and_authorize_resource` in your controller

**or**

```
def edit
    @critical_process = CriticalProcess.find(params[:id])
    #this here is what you use
    authorize! :edit, @critical_process
  end
```

in your edit method inside the critical process controller.

Comment: It turns out i was using ``authorize_resource`` and it wasn't working, because i tried the ``authorize! :edit, @critical_process`` in there and it worked. This is so annoying! thanks for the answer though ;)

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to keep this logic completely separate from models so that I don't have to dig into model code to find authorization issues.  In other words, user.can_edit checks for authorization which is what the ability file is supposed to be in charge of.  Shouldn't matter though... in this case I think you might have a problem inside the can_edit method.  I have used code that looks nearly identical to yours without problems many times like this:

```
can :manage, Record do |record|
  user.has_role?(:record_manager)
end
```

I suggest including your code for can_edit or use the debugger to see what value gets returned from can_edit.

Comment: Its not the can_edit method, I tried it in the console and it works, i also tried debugging the code in the console just like the CanCan docs suggest and that works as well. its very odd. i will include the can_edit code in the question now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the way you query for the records that are supposed to have the user as an editor.

I copy/pasted your code and built the other associations from scratch.
And testing it in the console it works as expected when I use it:

```
>> u = User.last
>> a = Ability.new(u)
>> a.can :edit, Role.last
false
```

The only thing I changed is the query for the records: it seemed to look for a record that owns the role (your Role has a **record_id**) but then looks for the same key under cp_secondary_id.

I think something is wrong in your query, but what depends on your schema and associations:

```
roles_as_editor.collect{ |x| Record.where(:cp_secondary_id => x.record_id) }.flatten.uniq
```

as I understood your code we are traversing associations like this:

```
User=>Assignment<=Role(boolean edit flag)<=Record
```